Cannot uninstall 'TBB'
I am trying to run this code for my yolov8 project.
pip install --upgrade torch torchvision torchaudio

But I am getting this error.
error: cannot uninstall 'tbb'. it is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
How can I solve this error?
I run this code for hoping to fix the error
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade torch torchvision torchaudio --ignore-installed tbb
Collecting torch

Then I get this error too
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that 
are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
inference 0.9.22 requires numpy<=1.25.2, but you have numpy 1.26.4 which is incompatible.
inference 0.9.22 requires pydantic>=2.0, but you have pydantic 1.9.0 which is incompatible.
jupyterlab-server 2.22.0 requires requests>=2.28, but you have requests 2.27.1 which is incompatible.
numba 0.57.1 requires numpy<1.25,>=1.21, but you have numpy 1.26.4 which is incompatible.
pyfume 0.3.4 requires numpy==1.24.4, but you have numpy 1.26.4 which is incompatible.
roboflow 1.1.27 requires urllib3>=1.26.6, but you have urllib3 1.25.4 which is incompatible.
s3fs 2023.4.0 requires fsspec==2023.4.0, but you have fsspec 2024.3.1 which is incompatible.
sphinx 5.0.2 requires colorama>=0.3.5; sys_platform == "win32", but you have colorama 0.2.5 which is incompatible.

